# create 2 d array with each_with_index

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am a newbie to Ruby.  I am trying to creating a `2d array` using `each_with_index` over an other array. ex:

```
arr = ["a","b","c"]
puts arr.each_with_index{|v,i| [v, i+1]}
```

But for some reason I see only 1d array.

```
a
b
c
```

instead of

```
a
1
b
2
c
3
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: thanks for downvoting. try this http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/9fc33

Comment: @nandu `arr.each_with_index.map {|v,i| [v, i+1]}` will actually created the `Array` you want or in more readable context i would suggest @philipyoo's `arr.map.with_index` the reason being is that `each` will always return the receiver regardless of the block unless the block mutates items inside the enumerable object. Which yours does not.

Comment: @engineersmnky. thanks. Just curious if you know why didn't `each_with_index` work

Comment: @nandu seem my updated comment. `each_with_index` relies on `each` and returns an `enum` not the array you want

Comment: @engineersmnky, aha!! thanks. thats something I didn't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best way, but for now this is one solution:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
new_arr = []

arr.each_with_index { |letter, idx| new_arr.push([letter, idx + 1])}
```

Here is another way:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
arr = arr.map.with_index { |el, idx| [el, idx + 1] }
```

Also note that using `puts` will print your statement with a new line. Using `p` will actually print out the object

Edit: And, I think I initially misunderstood your question. Luckily, the second method with `map.with_index` should be the one you're looking for. If you don't want to save the change, just don't set it with `arr =`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
arr.each.with_index(1).to_a
  #=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
```

Comment: This is better I guess. Thanks @cary